# Excel array formula to return names of empty columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have the following table called `cdc` in a sheet called `magic`.

[image: Excel table with four columns and 7 rows, two columns are empty]

My input table can vary in size since it's the output of a Power Query, but I assume it won't extend more than `A1:Z100` when in production.

In cell `A1` of sheet `result`, I need **an Excel array formula that returns only the names of empty columns in the input table**. In this specific example, it should return `{"C", "D")`. The resulting array should return only column names, not 0s or anything else.

In sheet `result`, the output of the array formula should look like this:

[image: array formula resulting range, with just the names of empty columns]

It's a pretty straightforward problem, but quite tricky.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=TOCOL(FILTER(Table1[#Headers],BYCOL(Table1,LAMBDA(col,SUM(--(col<>""))))=0))
```

[image]

Comment: I marked this one because, after testing all of them, I believe it's the easiest to read and comprehend.Thanks to all of you for your solutions nonetheless.

Comment: @andreucci Glad to know!

Answer (score 2):

This could also work:

`=TOCOL(IFS(MMULT(TOROW(ROW(cdc)^0),--cdc)=0,cdc[#Headers]),2)`

Answer (score 2):

### Get Headers of Blank Columns

```
=LET(table,cdc[#All],if_not_found,"",
    h,TAKE(table,1),
    d,DROP(table,1),
    r,ROWS(d),
TOCOL(FILTER(h,BYCOL(d,LAMBDA(c,COUNTBLANK(c)=r)),if_not_found)))
```

[image]